# Attempting to reordering UITableView using an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am attempting to edit the order of my UITableView while using Core Data and an NSFetchedResultsController. As I understand, Core Data does not have a built in method for rearranging objects in a Core Data model.

The idea was to create an array, reorder my objects there, and then write that data back to my model.

**NSFetchedResultsController**

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
}

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"listName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**moveRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath; {
    NSMutableArray *toDoItems = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    [toDoItems removeObject:managedObject];
    [toDoItems insertObject:managedObject atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *moc in toDoItems) {
        [moc setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"listName"];
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

When I hit my `Edit` button, I can rearrange the rows but as soon as I let the row go, my app crashes. Im not getting any kind of stack trace in the console when it crashes.

I set a breakpoint on exception and it seems to be crashing on this line

```
[moc setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"listName"];
```

My key name is correct. But I now realize this is completely wrong in that I am trying to set this as a number and that shouldnt be the case.

Any suggestion or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Either** amend your code to set a string value for the `listName`, something like this:

```
[moc setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%d",i++] forKey:@"listName"];
```

(but beware because by default this will sort as a string, so 11 comes before 2, etc).

**So, better,** add an integer attribute to your model, and use that to sort the fetched results controller.

Comment: That was a thought I had last night. I was looking at how other people had handled this as well and it seemed that quite a few people added an additional attribute to their entity to use for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy NSManagedObject. It's a managed object by core data. If you want a new one ask the context.